# Resize the width (shorter) on a mat-option element

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to resize (shorten) mat-options within an mat-select.
Unfortunately, I always get an extra area of padding.  Is there not a designed way for this?  Anyone have any experience?  Here is my StackBlitz, it's very close:

Basically I need all 3 dropdown items to actually be 100px wide on this StackBlitz [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-custom-options?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdropdown%2Fcustom-dropdown.component.scss).

### EDIT

I STILL NEED HELP

@David's answer is very close, there are just some issues with styling the cdk-overlay-container without `:host`

I'm not able to use `:host` as it will effect the other dropdowns on the screen when that is not intended.

Comment: Cant you just use CSS with more accurate selector (as this gets the precedence) or use `!important` ?

Comment: not really, could you help..  one of the main problems is the +32px.  or at least i cannot find the correct classes due to the quickness of the animation etc.  i'm aware of css and !Important but not having any luck.  and this transformPanel isn't the easiest element to override

Comment: here is my css https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-custom-options?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdropdown%2Fcustom-dropdown.component.scss

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-custom-options-b24xhb?file=src/app/dropdown/custom-dropdown.component.scss

Comment: This might help you debugging: In Chrome, you can slow down and even stop animations to inspect elements at a specific time: https://imgur.com/a/ro3y37R

Comment: @David that does help a lot!!  you've got it very close, there is just that little bit of padding left while it animates

Comment: When working with `mat-select` I found useful to just add a custom class and target that class on the `mat-form-field` you can then just remove `padding`, `margin` and set a `width`; I end up with something like this https://imgur.com/a/jcurGsk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better way to do it, but just using CSS you can do it like this

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane
{
  min-width: auto !important;
}

::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container
{
  display:inline-block;
}

::ng-deep .ng-animating .mat-option {
  margin-right: -32px;
}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-custom-options-b24xhb?file=src/app/dropdown/custom-dropdown.component.scss)

**Edit**

Theree is indeed a problem: the overlay container is common to material components. So if you style it like above, CSS rules will apply to all select components. Besides, the overlay container is outside of the component itself, so you cannot restrict the rule with a top level selector, like `:host`.

I created an example that adds/removes a custom class to/from the overlay so that the styles do not leak to other select components.

It's a bit of a hack, and they may be better solutions ( maybe if you create your own overlay)

It still does not work perfectly when you open/close the select

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-custom-options-nm2iqs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdropdown%2Fcustom-dropdown.component.ts)

Comment: this is good..  and i could accept it, but when I went to implement it I'm having problems with the ::ng-deeps effecting the other dropdowns and cdk-overlay-containers..  is there a way to keep the styling encapsulated to this 1 dropdown only?

Comment: I don't have access to my computer now. But you can add a class to a wrapping dmdiv and target that, or use :host selector if there is only one dropdown in the component. Ill modify the example tomorrow

Answer (score -1):

can be control by adding height and padding css into .mat-options class.

```
.mat-option{
   height: 30px !important;
   padding: 0 5px !important;
}
```